# Not enough memory to process a large text file and write it back to xml

Tags: java, xml

I am new with java programming and now I have an issue with processing a large text file. I'm writing code to process a string of a whole file, parsing it into a class where I will transform it into an xml. The challenge is that I can only process an output less than 70K lines; if I have more than 800K it will throw an error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space". Here are my sample files and codes.

Sample File 1

```
H|20090908|
D|ABASTECEDORA NAVAL Y INDUSTRIAL, S.A. ,N|10          |9|4PANAMA     |9|8  |        |                                                                                                                            |1|20090908|AMLA    |
D|ABDELNUR, NURY DE JESUS ,NULL           |15          |9|0PANAMA     |9|8  |        |                                                                                                                        |1|20090908|AMLA    |
D|ACECHILLY ,NULL                         |22          |9|0UNKNOWN    |9|8  |        |                                                                                                                        |1|20090908|AMLA    |
D|ACEFROSTY ,NULL                         |24          |9|0UNKNOWN    |9|8  |        |                                                                                                                        |1|20090908|AMLA    |
D|ACEFROSTY SHIPPING CO., LTD. ,NULL      |25          |9|0MALTA      |9|8  |        |                                                                                                                        |1|20090908|AMLA    |
T|0000013413|
```

Here is the Parser Class.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;



public class WatchlistParser {

public Object receiveExternal(Object callback) {
    Object result = null;

    try {
        result = this.process("external_watchlist", callback);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}

public Object receiveInternal(Object callback) {
    Object result = null;

    try {
        result = this.process("internal_watchlist", callback);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;

}

public Object process(String filename, Object data) {
    java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(data.toString());


    java.util.List<WatchlistEntryObject> list = new java.util.Vector<WatchlistEntryObject>();
    int entryCount = 1;

    String prefix="113";
    if (filename.equalsIgnoreCase("internal_watchlist")) {
        prefix = "113INT";
    }
    if (filename.equalsIgnoreCase("external_watchlist")) {
        prefix = "113EXT";
    }
    //         
    // read all watchlist entry and store it into a list
    SimpleDateFormat dateformatYYYYMMDD = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        // Get data lines
        if (line.startsWith("D")) {
            // System.out.println("-"+line);
            // parse the data line

            line = line.replace("&", "&amp;");
            line = line.replace("'", "''");
            line = line.replace(">", "&gt;");
            line = line.replace("<", "&lt;");
            String fields[] = line.split("\\|");
            // do validation
            // field.size must 4

            if (fields.length == 12) {
                // do work
                WatchlistEntryObject wo = new WatchlistEntryObject();
                wo.setName(fields[1].trim());
                wo.setId(fields[2].trim());
                wo.setIdType(fields[3].trim());
                wo.setAltID(fields[4].trim());
                wo.setAltIDType(fields[5].trim());
                wo.setReason(fields[6].trim());
                try {
                    java.util.Date dob = dateformatYYYYMMDD.parse(fields[7].trim());
                    wo.setDob(dateformatYYYYMMDD.format(dob));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    wo.setDob("");
                }
                //wo.setDob(fields[7].trim());
                wo.setRemark(fields[8].trim());
                // Set critical will map Y/1 to 1 N/2 to 2
                wo.setCriticalID(fields[9].trim());
                wo.setFileName(filename);
                wo.setLastMaintainDate(fields[10].trim());
                wo.setLastMaintainUser(fields[11].trim());
                wo.setWatchlistEntryID(wo.generateID(prefix, entryCount));
                wo.setLocation(entryCount);
                list.add(wo);
                entryCount++;
            }
        } // end of if

    } // end of while

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<Statement>DELETE FROM tbl_watch_list WHERE filename = '" + filename + "'</Statement>\n");
    java.util.Iterator<WatchlistEntryObject> iterator = list.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        WatchlistEntryObject entry = iterator.next();
        sb.append(entry.getInsertSQL() + "\n");

        //System.out.println(entry.getInsertSQL());

    }
    return encloseInXml(sb.toString());



            }



    //return sb.toString();
}

public String encloseInXml(String sql) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<?xml version ='1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'no'?>\n");
    sb.append("<VREMIT>\n");
    sb.append(sql);
    sb.append("</VREMIT>\n");
    return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the Object Class

```
public class WatchlistEntryObject  implements Cloneable{ //-----------------------[1]

private String name;
private String id;
private String idType;
private String altID;
private String altIDType;
private String reason;
private String dob;
private String remark;
private String criticalID;
private String lastMaintainDate;
private String lastMaintainUser;
private String watchlistEntryID;
private String fileName;
private String location;


/**
 * Generate id in this format xxx-ddmmyy-nnnnnn
 * where nnnnnn is the count.
 * @param count
 * @return 
 */


public static String generateID(String prefix,int count) {
    Date dateNow = new Date ();
    SimpleDateFormat dateformatYYYYMMDD = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
    StringBuilder nowYYYYMMDD = new StringBuilder(dateformatYYYYMMDD.format(dateNow));
    String temp = String.format(prefix+"-"+nowYYYYMMDD.toString() + "-%06d", count);
    return temp; 
}

public static String convertCID( String s) {

    return s;
}
// replace critical id from y to 1, n to 2

/**
 * @return the watchlistEntryID
 */
public String getWatchlistEntryID() {
    return watchlistEntryID;
}

/**
 * @param watchlistEntryID the watchlistEntryID to set
 */
public void setWatchlistEntryID(String watchlistEntryID) {
    this.watchlistEntryID = watchlistEntryID;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the idType
 */
public String getIdType() {
    return idType;
}

/**
 * @param idType the idType to set
 */
public void setIdType(String idType) {
     try {
        Byte.parseByte(idType);
        this.idType = idType;
    }catch (Exception e){
       this.idType ="9";       
    }

  //  this.idType = idType;
}

/**
 * @return the altID
 */
public String getAltID() {
    return altID;
}

/**
 * @param altID the altID to set
 */
public void setAltID(String altID) {

    this.altID = altID;
}

/**
 * @return the altIDType
 */
public String getAltIDType() {
    return altIDType;
}

/**
 * @param altIDType the altIDType to set
 */
public void setAltIDType(String altIDType) {
   try {
        Byte.parseByte(altIDType);
        this.altIDType = altIDType;
    }catch (Exception e){
       this.altIDType ="9";       
    }
}

/**
 * @return the reason
 */
public String getReason() {
    return reason;
}

/**
 * @param reason the reason to set
 */
public void setReason(String reason) {
      try {
        Byte.parseByte(reason);
        this.reason = reason;
    }catch (Exception e){
       this.reason ="7";       
    }

}

/**
 * @return the dob
 */
public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}

/**
 * @param dob the dob to set
 */
public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

/**
 * @return the remark
 */
public String getRemark() {
    return remark;
}

/**
 * @param remark the remark to set
 */
public void setRemark(String remark) {
    this.remark = remark;
}

/**
 * @return the criticalID
 */
public String getCriticalID() {

    return criticalID;
}
// inspect Critical Id and return "Y to 1" else set to "2".
/**
 * @param criticalID the criticalID to set
 */
public void setCriticalID(String myID) {

    if (myID.equalsIgnoreCase("N") || myID.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
        this.criticalID = "2";

    }else{
        this.criticalID = "1";
    }

}

/**
 * @return the lastMaintainDate
 */
public String getLastMaintainDate() {
    return lastMaintainDate;
}

/**
 * @param lastMaintainDate the lastMaintainDate to set
 */
public void setLastMaintainDate(String lastMaintainDate) {
    this.lastMaintainDate = lastMaintainDate;
}

/**
 * @return the lastMaintainUser
 */
public String getLastMaintainUser() {
    return lastMaintainUser;
}

/**
 * @param lastMaintainUser the lastMaintainUser to set
 */
public void setLastMaintainUser(String lastMaintainUser) {
    this.lastMaintainUser = lastMaintainUser;
}

 /**
 * @return the fileName plus with date e.g yyMMdd
 */
public String getFileName() {
          return fileName;
}

/**
 * @param fileName the fileName to set
 */
public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

 // get location
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

/**
 * @param getting the location = object count
 */
public void setLocation(int loc) {

    this.location = Integer.toString(loc);

}




public String getInsertSQL() {

     return " <Statement> INSERT INTO tbl_watch_list( watch_entry_id,entry_data,id,id_type,alt_id,alt_id_type,reason,date_of_birth,remark,critical_identifier,filename,dt_last_chg,username,location) VALUES ('"+watchlistEntryID+"','"+name+"','"+id+"','"+idType+"','"+altID+"','"+altIDType+"','"+reason+"','"+dob+"','"+remark+"','"+criticalID+"','"+fileName+"', getDate() ,'Xgate','"+location+"'); </Statement>";          

 }
}
```

And lastly the Test Class

```
public class TestParser {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // read the file into a string
    String data = "";
    try {//reading the files and convert it to UTF-8
      data = new String(readFile("H:\\external_watchlist.txt"), "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Trace.error("Encoding Exception", e);//catch all exceptions
    }
    WatchlistParser parser = new WatchlistParser();
    String sql = (String) parser.receiveExternal(data);            
    System.out.println(sql);
}

public static byte[] readFile(String path) {
    try {

        //java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(path));
        java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(path);
        java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (fis.available() > 0) {
            int len = fis.read(buffer);
            bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        fis.close();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Trace.error("Read File Exception", e);
    }

    return null;


    }
}
```

I'm considering to scan the delimeter "D|" in the string to count the maximum line of object that i can parse like for an example every 10K and write the output to a separate files to avoid the "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error.

Is there any other ways to do it?? I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Stream the input to the output. You don't need to keep more than 1 line / xml element in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are trying to read the entire input file into memory (RAM).  This is causing your error.

Rather than allocate more memory, you need to read small pieces of the file, generate XML for that small piece, and append that XML to your output file. Don't try and hold the whole file in memory at once.

Comment: I know, but the reading and writing were triggered by another class using Oracle Weblogic. It will automatically read the whole file placed in designated folder and parse the whole content of the files to this class. By considering that, is it still possible avoid the memory error?

Comment: I'm not familiar with oracle weblogic. I'd find a way to break this big file into multiple files, or find another method of processing, or (and I don't recommend this) increase program heap size. The only way to prevent memory errors with large files is to process in chunks, or increase memory. There's no alternative.

Comment: It may help if he at least **writes** the xml-stream to a file, instead to a stringbuilder.

Comment: @Ingo right, that's what I suggest in my question. And maybe the question was edited, but I don't see huge writes to a stringbuilder?

Comment: Look at the bottom half of Parser class - he does this: `encloseInXml(sb.toString())` only to write it to yet another StringBuilder and return the toString(), so he has the output at least 4 times in memory for a moment.

Comment: @Ingo You're correct, my mistake. I searched for **StringBuilder** not **StringBuffer**.

Answer (score 1):

You do this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("<Statement>DELETE FROM tbl_watch_list WHERE filename = '" + filename + "'</Statement>\n");
java.util.Iterator<WatchlistEntryObject> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    WatchlistEntryObject entry = iterator.next();
    sb.append(entry.getInsertSQL() + "\n");

    //System.out.println(entry.getInsertSQL());

}
return encloseInXml(sb.toString()); 
}

public String encloseInXml(String sql) {
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  sb.append("<?xml version ='1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8' standalone = 'no'?>\n");
  sb.append("<VREMIT>\n");
  sb.append(sql);
  sb.append("</VREMIT>\n");
  return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

So, you collect the  sql statements in a StringBuilder.
Then you pass the String that is therein to encloseInXml().
And there you write the same data again to a StringBuilder, and return toString() of that.
At this point, you have the strings with the SQL Statements 2 to 4 times in memory.

Why not just write to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a LineNumberReader:

```
LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```

Run a loop to read each line:

```
String data = lineReader.readLine();
```

Read each line process it and write to OutputStream, hoping this helps.

Cheers !!